# Proving that something is a manifold from the definition

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Consider a set

$$M = \{ (s\cos t, s\sin t, t) \colon s,t\in \mathbb{R}\}\subset \mathbb{R}^3.$$

I am asked to show from the definition that $M$ is a 2-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is say for each $x\in M$ there is an open set $U$ (relative to $M$), an open set $V\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ together with a diffeomorphism $\varphi\colon U\to M$.

Building $\varphi$ (subject to $x$) seems to be difficult. I tried to employ some version of theorem about local dipheomorphisms but no version seems to be applicable here.

May I ask for help?

Comment: sine and cosine are diffeomorphisms when suitably restricted.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111197 from one hour ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is relatively straightforward, computing the derivative of the parametrization, which I will call $\phi$, gives

$$d\phi=\begin{pmatrix}\cos t \\ \sin t \\ 0\end{pmatrix}ds+\begin{pmatrix} -s\sin t \\ s\cos t \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\,dt$$

clearly the two vectors are linearly independent since the latter has component $dt$ and the former has component $0$ in the third, so that you get two linearly independent vectors at every point, hence the matrix is always rank $2$, and you have a local diffeomorphism.

Comment: @robjohn: The Hessian of _what_? Hessians are usually for scalar-valued functions, aren't they?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Sorry, I was thinking about $$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial\varphi_1}{\partial s}&\frac{\partial\varphi_2}{\partial s}\\\frac{\partial\varphi_1}{\partial t}&\frac{\partial\varphi_2}{\partial t}\end{bmatrix}$$ This should be invertible for a diffeomorphism, should it not?

Comment: @robjohn: I suspected as much, but that one is missing the third component ...

Comment: @robjohn that's only when you're dealing with maps between the same dimensional spaces, the matrix rank is what's important, not the invertibility (most aren't square matrices, as in this case). I'm showing the rank $2$ condition more directly. If you insist on determinant methods, you can take the two vectors I have there and wedge them, and see you get something non-zero in the exterior algebra, but that seems to be overkill for these two vectors when a more direct observation can be made.

Comment: @AdamHughes: That makes sense. There are two independent vectors. I guess I was limiting the orientation of my patches. Sorry for the interruption, and thanks for clearing my mind. (+1)

Comment: @robjohn not at all, glad we were able to figure things out. :-)